# Langevin Dynamics simulation at different values of friction coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, stochastic-processes, molecular-dynamics

I am a beginner in the area of Langevin Dynamics simulation. The following equation is solved numerically:

$m_i\frac{d^2r_i}{dt^2}=F_{int}-\gamma\frac{dr_i}{dt}+R(t)$

In Langevin Dynamics simulation one can adjust the friction coefficient($\gamma$) to bring the kinetic temperature of the system to a desired equilibrium value.  There are works in the literature where people have studied some property of the system ( for example some autocorrelation function ) at different values of friction cofficient keeping the value of temperature fixed at a certatin value. So my question is :how is it possible to get the same value of equilibrium temperature at different values of friction coefficient ? Will the temperature not change if I change the friction coefficient ?

Comment: What are the correlations of the noise $R(t)$? Without defining the two first moments, the meaning of the symbol $R$ is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stochastic differential equation you write makes physical sense for any $\gamma\gt0$. From all possible values of $\gamma$, only one is compatible with a solution in thermal equilibrium with a reservoir at temperature $T$. Supposing arbitrary correlations for the noise:
$$\langle R(t)\rangle=0 \quad \quad \langle R(t)R(t')\rangle=D\delta(t-t') $$
The relation that ensures a steady equilibrium state is:
$$\gamma_{eq}(T)=\frac{D}{2 k_B T}.$$
There is no problem at all in integrating numerically the stochastic differential equation with $\gamma\ne\gamma_{eq}(T)$, for example, with a [Milstein method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method). The only thing is that a system with $\gamma\ne\gamma_{eq}(T)$ is not in equilibrium with a reservoir at temperature $T$.

As the last remark, note that systems out of equilibrium can also have steady states.

A good reference on numerical methods to simulate SDEs oriented to physicists is: [Toral, Raúl, and Pere Colet. Stochastic numerical methods: an introduction for students and scientists. John Wiley & Sons, 2014.](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&lr=&id=N2vsAwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PT9&dq=raul%20toral%20stochastic&ots=iXN6dciVKi&sig=X8e2f87YXitUhopU0mlqd4gUmAw#v=onepage&q=raul%20toral%20stochastic&f=false)

Comment: When I do molecular dynamics simulation for example with Langevin equations, I monitor whether the temperature start fluctuating around the equilibrium value ( $T$ here ) after a certain number of timesteps. I can then present the results as results obtained at temperature $T$. So, if my temperature doesn't relax to $T$ after a couple of time steps when $\gamma \neq \gamma_{eq}$(acc to my understanding this is the meaning of your answer), can I present my results as results obtained at temperature $T$ ?

Comment: I want to know how can I get results at different friction coefficients keeping  temperature fixed.

Comment: @bubucodex Usually the temperature is fixed and you monitor fluctuations of the energy. What is the meaning of a varying temperature? How the temperature depends on the state of the system?

Comment: Yes, I give temperature as a fixed input value and monitor the instantaneous temperature which should fluctuate around the input value of temperature. The energy also fluctuates around a certain equilibrium value. Where have I mentioned about varying temperature ?

Comment: I am saying, suppose I have a function $f(t)$ and want to plot the function with respect to $t$ using the data generated from a Langevin Dynamics simulation. I want plots at 3 different friction coefficients $\gamma_{1}$, $\gamma_{2}$ and $\gamma_{3}$. But for all the plots the temperature should be same ( say $T$ ). How can I get this ? Will the system relax to same temperature $T$ for $\gamma_{1}$,$\gamma_{2}$ and $\gamma_{3}$.

Comment: Your question and arguments are difficult to follow. You say that the temperature is fixed, yet it fluctuates. This is nonsense, it is either fixed or not. If it is not fixed, how do you monitor the "instantaneous temperature"? What is the relation of this "instantaneous temperature" with your SDE? As I was saying in my answer, in principle, you can have any coefficient (e.g. $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, $\gamma_3$) for any value of $T$. The only thing is that the system you are modeling might be out of equilibrium.

Comment: By "fixed" temperature I mean the desired value of temperature($T$ in our case) in a simulation (probably I should not have said like this). By "instantaneous" temperature I mean the temperature that can be calculated from the knowledge of velocities(since, $\frac{3}{2}NK\tau=0.5Σ_{i=1}^Nm_i_{i}^2$. Here $\tau$ can be calculated at each timestep in the simulation from the knowledge of velocities and I call this the instantaneous temperature. At equilibrium when I plot $\tau$
 w.r.t timestep it should show fluctuation about $T$. Am I right ?

Comment: I am not sure about the relation of "instantaneous temperature" with the SDE. I have not studied that yet. As you have said in the answer for $\gamma\neq\gamma_{eq}$
 the system will not be in equilibrium with a reservoir of temperature T. So my question is : will $\tau$ fluctuate about 
$T$ in that case ? And if not, shall I be correct if I present my result (for any quantity say () ) as results obtained at temperature $T$ ?

Comment: Now I understand you. First, for $\gamma \ne \gamma_{eq}$, $\tau$ will not fluctuate about $T$. It will fluctuate about $T'=\frac{D}{2K \gamma}$. So you can either interpret your model as an equilibrium process with temperature $T'$ or as an out-of-equilibrium process at temperature $T$.

Comment: I think that a much better way to view this problem is to link the temperature to the size of fluctuations ($D$ in my answer). Only when the drift ($\gamma$) and the fluctuations ($D(T)$) fulfill the [fluctuation-dissipation relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem), the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: Yeah, now its clear to me.